# Sorting list of list in Java using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, compiler-errors

I have a list of list elements, now I want to sort that list using lambda expression, but I am getting compilation error:

Here is working code without lambda:

```
Collections.sort(positions, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
    public int compare(List<Integer> ele1, List<Integer> ele2) {
        // some logic here
        return some_number;
    }
});
```

Now using lamda, I am trying this:

```
positions.sort((List<Integer> ele1, List<Integer> ele2) -> {

});
```

But getting this compilation error:

```
The method sort(Comparator<? super List<Integer>>) in the type List<List<Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments ((List<Integer> ele1, List<Integer> ele2) -> {})
```

Comment: You forgot to return some_number from your lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement in your lambda:

```
positions.sort((List<Integer> ele1, List<Integer> ele2) -> {
    // logic...
    return some_number;
});
```

Note, however, that the idiomatic way to sort such a list in Java 8 is with a `Comparator#comparing` call:

```
positions.sort(Comparator.comparing(l -> logic_that_produces_some_comparable));
```

Answer (score 0):

`.sort` expects a function that takes in two lists and returns an integer.

The lambda you have provided takes in two lists and returns nothing.

You need to return a value in your lambda.